# Grid Horizontal Scroll Bar (Floating)

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento

I use Magento for my website store.

The problem I face is the default horizontal scroll bar displayed within admin grids are useless when the number of rows extends further than the page displayed within a browser.
This makes accessing the scroll bar for practical use difficult.

For example, when i navigate to "Manage Products" in my admin backend. The products grid horizontal bar only shows once the user scrolls all the way down to the bottom of the page.

I want to be able to scroll horizontally from the very first row, therefore being able to view product attributes which are displayed further to the right (out of page view).

I've found a jquery solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/45rEs/show/

But I don't know how to implement it into my store.
If you view the above url, you will see that the horizontal scroll bar appears anywhere that a horizontal overflow is established.

Comment: anyone know a solution? The current horizontal scroll is very frustrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css` --> `.hor-scroll` class --> remove `overflow: auto;`

Comment: Good stuff man!! thanks for putting in the effort to help me :)